# Error: 17828, Severity: 20, State: 3. in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2(Standard Edition)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms, packet

I can able to login the sql server through `SSMS`.But while connecting the server from other applications it throwing the below error.

> Error: 17828, Severity: 20, State: 3. The prelogin packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library. [CLIENT: <>]

Comment: Define other applications: .net or java?

Comment: Its java application @gbn

Comment: I have the same issue when I trying to connect from VS 2017

Comment: Same issue from a java application.